# Overlapping data labels on line plot (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, label

[image]

On this plot I'd like to show relative changes in consumption of 3 different products per quarter. But I have an issue with overlapping data labels, which makes it difficult to "understand" this plot. Is there any option how to maintain data labels so that they go one below other?

I tried to enter data labels position manually for each line, but it didn't worked out as expected:

```
`for i, j in products['CATEGORY'].items():     
    ax[1].annotate(
        "{:.0f}%".format(j),                    
        xy=(i, j),                    
        xytext=(-50, 15),                    
        textcoords='offset points',                    
        fontsize=20,                    
        color=annot_colors[2])`
```